# Entradas JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Es mi primer post aca, y me gustaria hacerles una pregunta con la cual me solucionarian la vida con un proyecto.
Estoy desarollando una pagina web en HTML, CSS y JS, en esta, tengo una especie de "Calculadora virtual". Mi idea era pedirle al usuario que ingrese algunos valores, y en base a los mismos, se muestre un resultado. Se que eso se hace con JavaScript, pero no se como hacer para que el mismo me tome los valores ingresados por el usuario, los sume, y devuelva un resultado. Por ejemplo.

Ingrese numero 1 = (Aca el usuario tiene un cuadro de texto donde pone, por ejemplo, el numero 2)
Ingrese numero 2 = (idem)
Que haya un boton que diga "resolver", o se haga solo, no es el punto principal, y que aparezca el 
El resultado es = 4;

Estuve buscando en internet, pero la mayoria te lo muestra con el cartel que aparece arriba, pero a mi me gustaria que sea en la misma pagina.

desde ya mil gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', main, false);

function main() {

  var na = document.querySelector('#numA');
  var nb = document.querySelector('#numB');
  var calc = document.querySelector('#calc');
  var res = document.querySelector('#result');

  calc.addEventListener('click', function() {
    res.innerHTML = 'La suma es ' + (parseFloat(na.value) + parseFloat(nb.value));
  }, false);

}
```

```html
<input id="numA">
<input id="numB">
<button id="calc"> Sumar </button>
<span id="result"></span>
```

Para probarlo da click en el boton de "Ejecutar" de abajo.

Comment: Ahora lo pruebo! Mil gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que tienes dos input de tipo numérico y uno tipo submit

```
<input type="number" id="numero-uno">
<input type="number" id="numero-dos">
<input type="submit" id="resolver" value="Resolver">
```

Primero haces referencia a los elementos html

```
let inputUno = document.getElementById('numero-uno');
let inputDos = document.getElementById('numero-dos');
let inputResolver = document.getElementById('resolver');
```

Después haces una función para que al darle click al botón de resolver guarde los valores.

```
inputResolver.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let numeroUno = inputUno.val();
  let numeroDos = inputDos.val();
  let resultado = numeroUno + numeroDos;
  alert(resultado);
});
```

Comment: Excelente la explicacion! Ahora lo pruebo. Mil gracias !!